# How to save the count on a counter app and present that count in a list showing previous counts made? (using react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, counter

I have created a simple counter app that allows you to increment, decrement and reset the count. The next goal is to save the count, where you are able to show a history of previous calculations. Beginning with creating a function component for the 'Save Count' button.

I have gone about this by creating an empty useState array. Then creating an onClickFunction for saveCount, where the savedCount applies a spread operator to the count and then I map through the array every time the 'Save Count' button is pressed. This is based on a example of 'useState with Array' in the link below:

https://daveceddia.com/usestate-hook-examples/

You can find the code I have attempted below (also using this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/counter-app-project-save-nx7x6?file=/src/index.js:286-1297) :

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const savedCount = useState([]);

  const incrementCount = increment => {
    setCount(count + increment);
  };

  const decrementCount = decrement => {
    setCount(count - decrement);
  };

  const resetCount = () => {
    setCount(0);
  };

  const saveCount = () => {
    savedCount([
      ...count,
      {
        id: count.length
      }
    ]);
    resetCount();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ButtonIncrement increment={1} onClickFunction={incrementCount} />
      <ButtonIncrement increment={10} onClickFunction={incrementCount} />
      <ButtonDecrement decrement={1} onClickFunction={decrementCount} />
      <ButtonDecrement decrement={10} onClickFunction={decrementCount} />
      <Reset onClickFunction={resetCount} />
      <span>{count}</span>
      <Save onClickFunction={saveCount} />
      <ul>
        {savedCount.map(count => (
          <li key={count.id}>count</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you have a specific question?

Comment: Have your saveCount state resemble the syntax of your count state, like `[savedCount, useSavedCount] = useState([]);`, add previous saveCounts and the current count to the new saveCount using the `...` spread operator and use the `index` argument from `Array.prototype.map` to set the key:  https://codesandbox.io/s/counter-app-project-save-gr49p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [savedCounts, setSavedCounts] = useState([]);

  const incrementCount = increment => {
    setCount(count + increment);
  };

  const decrementCount = decrement => {
    setCount(count - decrement);
  };

  const resetCount = () => {
    setCount(0);
  };

  const saveCount = () => {
    setSavedCounts([...savedCounts, count]);
    resetCount();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ButtonIncrement increment={1} onClickFunction={incrementCount} />
      <ButtonIncrement increment={10} onClickFunction={incrementCount} />
      <ButtonDecrement decrement={1} onClickFunction={decrementCount} />
      <ButtonDecrement decrement={10} onClickFunction={decrementCount} />
      <Reset onClickFunction={resetCount} />
      <span>{count}</span>
      <Save onClickFunction={saveCount} />
      <ul>
        {savedCounts.map((savedCount, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{savedCount}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Fix `savedCount` as `useState` returns an array (tuple of `[state,setState]`).
2. Fix `saveCount` while using functional `useState`.
3. Render list items with **unique** `key` prop.

```
const [savedCount, setSavedCount] = useState([]);
const saveCount = () => {
  setSavedCount(prev => [...prev, { id: count }]);
  resetCount();
};

<ul>
  {savedCount.map((count, index) => (
    <li key={index}>count: {count.id}</li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

[image: Edit Counter App Project (+Save)]